# php more readable if statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I am just wondering if there is better way to solve my situatuion:

I have 6 independent variables to check. But if any of conditions is true it shouldnt check other. Normally I would write:

```
    if (cond1 ) { 
          statement 
    } else {
       if ( cond2 ) {
          statement      
       } else {
         if (cond3) {
             statement
         } else {
         ...    
         }
       }
    }
```

Surely you would admit it doesnt look good or it is not easy to read although it works. Do you know any other ways to write such if statement maybe using other notation or functions (switch? while?)

Comment: If your conditions are simple text/numeric matches, Use a `switch`

Comment: i cant, condition is return value of function and ion each condition the function name is different

Comment: If each function returns a boolean, I think you can `switch(true) { case func1(): ... }` Kind of a hack, though. Just stick with a clear if-elif-else.

Comment: very good idea to turn switch statement upside down :) i like it

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can do

```
if (cond1 ) { 
    statement 
} elseif ( cond2 ) {
    statement
} elseif ( cond3 ) {
    statement
}
```

See [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php)

Comment: just like old time basic :D

Comment: Aah, you beat me too it :o

Comment: @Kalreg most languages with a C-like syntax have "else if".

Comment: Can't believe how you lived years without `elseif`.

Answer (score 1):

[A more stylish way:](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php)

```
if(cond1):
    statement1
elseif(cond2):
    statement2
elseif(cond3):
    statement3
elseif(cond4):
    statement4
elseif(cond5):
    statement5
elseif(cond6):
    statement6
endif;
```

---

This is how you do it with a `switch()`:

```
$a = 10;
$b = 100;

switch(true){
    case ($a > $b):
        echo 'a is bigger than b';break;
    case ($b > $a):
        echo 'b is bigger than a';break;
}
```

Comment: You should use brackets - it's easier to read and most coding standards prefer it.

Comment: @kissmyface awkward nickname, anyway I do agree with you, I just though of providing another "way" of doing it. Further if the statements aren't that big, this one would look "better" in my opinion ...

Comment: ;-) It's a reference rather than an invitation. I'm going to change it though

Comment: The switch makes you add the break. It's more verbose and less readable. That's why you usually don't use this solution in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (cond1 ) { 
          statement 
    } else {
       if ( cond2 ) {
          statement      
       } else {
         if (cond3) {
             statement
         } else {
         ...    
         }
       }
    }
```

Change to:

```
if (Cond1){

}elseif (cond2){

}elseif (cond3){

}
```